# SQL to change user in Sybase IQ

Tags: sap-iq

Is there an SQL in Sybase IQ so that I can change the username ? 
In Sybase ASE you can change database by the 'USE' statement or in PostgreSQL which has SET search_path TO myschema; 
Any similar SQL in Sybase IQ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the prefix for a user e.g. something like "dbo"."my_fancy_table". IQ is not having something like schema you would change in PostgreSQL with `SET search_path`.